# Filtered port with virtual server setup on a NAT

Tags: networking, ssh, router, iptables, nat

I have a `Symphony SY602` ADSL router and I want configure a dynamic DNS to access my system remotely. I made a NAT virtual server in routers configuration and this is what I configured:

```
Server Name     External Port Start     External Port End   Protocol    Internal Port     Start     Internal Port End   Server IP Address
SSH             2222                    2222                TCP/UDP     2222                        2222                192.168.1.2
```

While I can connect to ssh using my internal IP address `192.168.1.2`, over WAN this operation will stock in connecting to the port.

Here is an `nmap -sS` result on my ip:

```
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
23/tcp   open     telnet
80/tcp   open     http
2222/tcp filtered EtherNet/IP-1
5431/tcp open     park-agent
```

As it is obvious the port is filtered. I checked `iptables` and it's disabled, but I can't find why this port is filtered!

Comment: From where did you try to use `nmap` and your SSH client? Inside your own network?

Comment: Yes! Actually using the 192.168.1.2 system.

Comment: Unless your router does NAT reflection (aka NAT loopback, NAT hairpinning, ...), you can’t test it that way. What you see on `nmap` are your router’s internal services. Your connection has to come from the WAN side.

Comment: Using [this service](http://nmap.online-domain-tools.com/) I ran another `nmap` session and as you suggested the port is open but, I can't still get ssh working! How can I figure out what the problem is?

Comment: @DanielB Thank you, It's working from other computers. It's awesome ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to wrap this up, as an answer:

When trying to test/use NAT Port Forwarding from the “local” network, your router has to have NAT reflection (AKA NAT loopback, NAT hairpinning) enabled.

If it isn’t enabled, the router receives the packets from the local network, sees “Oh, I’m the destination host”, and starts processing the packet right away, bypassing the part of the network subsystem where port forwarding takes place.